# Separate the Strings with out using reverse method

Tags: java, string

An Array contain String of palindrome and  other  String. Separate Palindrome Strings with out using String reverse method?

Comment: Why even add that content.. Leaving empty would not have made a difference..

Comment: You could have at least removed from the title the number of the question your teacher asked...

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String pal) {

    if (pal.length() <= 1) {
        return true;        // BASE CASE.
    }

    // Get the first and last characters of the String.
    char first = pal.charAt(0);
    char last = pal.charAt(pal.length()-1);

    if (Character.isLetter(first) && Character.isLetter(last)) {

        if (first != last) {
            return false;           // BASE CASE.
        }
        else {
            Palindrome sub = new Palindrome(
            pal.substring(1,pal.length()-1));
            return sub.isPalindrome();  // RECURSIVE CASE.
        }
    }
    else if (!Character.isLetter(first)) {
        Palindrome sub = new Palindrome(pal.substring(1));
        return sub.isPalindrome();      // RECURSIVE CASE.
    }
    else {
        Palindrome sub = new Palindrome(pal.substring(0, pal.length()-1));
        return sub.isPalindrome();      // RECURSIVE CASE.
    }
}
```

you can find a palindrome class here http://users.dickinson.edu/~braught/courses/cs132s03/code/Palindrome.src.html, write a for loop and check for palindromes, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this. Let searchStrings be the ArrayList containing the Strings to be searched.

```
for (String str : searchStrings) {
    char[] strArray = str.toCharArray();
    int i = 0;
    int j = strArray.length - 1;
    while (true) {
        if (strArray[i] != strArray[j]) {
            System.out.println(str + " is not a palindrome.");
            break;
        }

        if (i == j || i > j) {
            System.out.println(str + " is a palindrome.");
            break;
        }

        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```